# Does PrimeFaces can not accept class attribute?

Tags: primefaces

Does PrimeFaces can not accept class attribute?

the code above is producing error code: Exception during request processing:
Caused by javax.servlet.ServletException with message: "Setter not found for property class"

How can I assign  class attribute for PrimeFaces tags?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `styleClass` attribute, instead of `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for the [`styleClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-page002.htm#BNARK) attribute.

> #### 10.2.1.4 The style and styleClass Attributes
>
> The `style` and `styleClass` attributes allow you to specify CSS styles for the rendered output of your tags. [Displaying Error Messages with the h:message and h:messages Tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-page002.htm#BNASO) describes an example of using the style attribute to specify styles directly in the attribute. A component tag can instead refer to a CSS class.
>
> The following example shows the use of a `dataTable` tag that references the style class `list-background`:
>
> ```
> <h:dataTable id="items"
>              ...
>              styleClass="list-background"
>              value="#{cart.items}"
>              var="book">
> ```
>
> The style sheet that defines this class is `stylesheet.css`, which will be included in the application. For more information on defining styles, see the Cascading Style Sheets specifications and drafts at http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/.